# SCTP stay Disconnected

Tags: jboss, restcomm, sctp, mobicents, cap

I am trying to install and execute JSS7 Stack over eclipse-EE from local  Linux 
 machine, Currently using JBOSS version- `7.1`.
Linux machine details ->

```
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.10
```

JDK installed -> `java version "1.7.0_80"`

SCTP installed -> `lksctp-tools-1.0.6-3.el5.i386.rpm`

I have imported the JSS7 project from GIT into my workspace.. JBOSS and JMX tool is connected and call is been executed ..

Result is the SCTP is not getting connected , listed below are the error logs:

*On GUI :-

```
L1 State -> SCTP: Disconnected  M3UA: pFsm:DOWN lFsmP:DOWN
L2 state -> SCCP: Rspc: Enabled  Rss: Enabled
L3 state -> TCAP+CAP: Started
```

*In Terminal logs :-

```
6520 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.mobicents.protocols.sctp.netty.NettySctpManagementImpl  - Removing allocated resources: Servers=0, Associations=1
6521 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.mobicents.protocols.sctp.netty.NettyAssociationImpl  - Management requested to stop Association [name=Ass_main, associationType=CLIENT, ipChannelType=SCTP, hostAddress=200.20.20.20, hostPort=9999, peerAddress=100.10.10.10, peerPort=9999, serverName=, extraHostAddress=[]]
7078 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl  - M3UA configuration file path /xyz/SimM3uaServer_main_m3ua1.xml
7116 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl  - Error setting Assciation=Ass_main for the AspFactory=testasp while loading from XML
java.lang.Exception: No Association found for name=Ass_main

    at org.mobicents.protocols.sctp.netty.NettySctpManagementImpl.getAssociation(NettySctpManagementImpl.java:991)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.loadActualData(M3UAManagementImpl.java:1126)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.loadVer2(M3UAManagementImpl.java:1166)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.load(M3UAManagementImpl.java:1040)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.start(M3UAManagementImpl.java:292)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulator.level1.M3uaMan.initM3ua(M3uaMan.java:652)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulator.level1.M3uaMan.start(M3uaMan.java:549)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulator.management.TesterHostImpl.start(TesterHostImpl.java:503)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulatorgui.TestingForm$5.actionPerformed(TestingForm.java:256)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

7118 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl  - Error starting the AspFactory=testasp while loading from XML
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.AspFactoryImpl.start(AspFactoryImpl.java:196)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.loadActualData(M3UAManagementImpl.java:1134)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.loadVer2(M3UAManagementImpl.java:1166)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.load(M3UAManagementImpl.java:1040)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.m3ua.impl.M3UAManagementImpl.start(M3UAManagementImpl.java:292)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulator.level1.M3uaMan.initM3ua(M3uaMan.java:652)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulator.level1.M3uaMan.start(M3uaMan.java:549)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulator.management.TesterHostImpl.start(TesterHostImpl.java:503)
    at org.restcomm.protocols.ss7.tools.simulatorgui.TestingForm$5.actionPerformed(TestingForm.java:256)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Please let me know , where am going wrong?.. i want the SCTP to get connected..

Comment: I don't know if its too late. But the issue seems to be in M3UA config.

Error starting the AspFactory=testasp while loading from XML
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @TharakaDevinda i checked M3UA config file it fine i think , could you please elaborate to me which particular parameter seems to be wrong that is causing this exception.